# Could Apache DBCP validate connections on each use?

Tags: apache-commons-dbcp

Our production people are claiming that they are pretty sure that the Apache DBCP connection pooling system is validating a connection on each use, that is, every time before it issues a query via that connection. But the DBCP config at http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html does not seem to provide any such option that could be obtained by default. It seems that the only two options are on getting a connection or on returning it.

The team claims that they determined this using a tool called DynaTrace.

Could someone throw some light on this please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar when using `testOnBorrow` (which will issue a validation query every time a connection is requested from the pool) and requesting a new connection for every statement. Sharing the exported dynaTrace session (if you have access to it) could help with diagnosing this.